# Obtaining set within template using template tags

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got a model of Review and a model of Answer. Multiple answers are related to each review by way of a foreign key as per below. Let's assume that I have 5 instances of the Review model and for each instance, there are 3 instances of a related Answer model. I'm trying to display all 15 of these answers in my template, but the code in my template isn't working.

**Views.py**

```
reviews = Review.objects.filter(user=user)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)    
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.user)

class Answer(models.Model):
    review = models.ForeignKey(Review, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    answer = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.review)
```

**template.html**

```
      {% for review in reviews %}

            {% for i in review.answer_set %} #I believe this is the problem

                 {{i.answer}}

            {% endfor %}

      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `{% for i in review.answer_set.all %}`